# Dividing the screen into equal parts

Tags: android

I'm working on a project where I want to divide the screen into 3 equal parts, so that I can place the merged image that fit the single image in each part. so that I cannot worry about the size of the image.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

**Main Activity**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView img;

ArrayList<Bitmap> listBmp;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
}

public void btnClick(View v){

 listBmp=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();


listBmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.images));

listBmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img1))     

listBmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img2));      

listBmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img3));      

listBmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img4));    

listBmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img4));   

listBmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img4));     

listBmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img4))     

listBmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img4));

    Bitmap mergedImg= combineImageIntoOne(listBmp);

    img.setImageBitmap(mergedImg);

}

private Bitmap combineImageIntoOne(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap) {

    int w = 0, h = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.size(); i++) {

        if (i < bitmap.size() - 1) {

            w = bitmap.get(i).getWidth() > bitmap.get(i + 1).getWidth() ?bitmap.get(i).getWidth() : bitmap.get(i + 1).getWidth();

        }

        h += bitmap.get(i).getHeight();

    }


    Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(temp);

    int top = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.size(); i++) {

        Log.d("HTML", "Combine: "+i+"/"+bitmap.size()+1);


        top = (i == 0 ? 0 : top+bitmap.get(i).getHeight());

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(i), 0f, top, null);

    }
    return temp;


}
```

it is working well but as add more images the merged is getting small. so I wanted to fix the size on screen.

Comment: Can you show us your code and things you have tried?

Comment: post any sample image or the xml you tried!

Comment: please add some more details.

Comment: add image to post with issued one & expected result

Answer (score 0):

set the imageview weight under Linear layout in your layout file.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content
android:layout_weight="3">
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @ Doremon I have a merged image it means single one, to which image view i have to assign it?

Answer (score 0):

Well your question isn't enough clear here. But I think you're trying to set 3 images in single layout activity vertically. You can try as follows

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
        <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/your_img1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/your_img2"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"                            
                        android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/your_img3"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `android:scaleType="fitXY"` will adjust the size. The `scaleType` will adjust the image as you have given the `length` and `width` of your view.

Let me know if you've problem with this.

Comment: @paluru this is for 3 images, if you've merged these, then you must have a single image, right?

Comment: Then if you want to set without worrying about size, then remove other `ImageView` and use only 1 with that single image and add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` .